# How to display object ID on standard page without any use of custom development

Tags: salesforce-id

I have a requirement in which I need to display ID on standard page textbox without using formula field, So please some one help me out so that I can achieve that. Is there any way that I can set it's default value to this.

Comment: Did you try <your custom object>.Id?

Comment: your question is not clear ? where you want to display Id ? in text field? or you can create a formula field

Comment: You can even drag the record id into the page layout. Also, the id is included in the standard page URL. So, in a way, it is always displayed.

Comment: try to create a formula `=RecordId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a formula field called you object.Id type text and add it to your page layout...